# Delete JNI local references in android app

Tags: android, cordova, java-native-interface

Hi In my android phonegap app i have used below link and called native code.Using that native code added two numbers.Using this native code how can i delete the jni local references?

Here is the link: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html

I am getting this error in logcat:

```
JNI error local reference table overflow 512 entries
VM aborting
```

To solve this error i need to delete the jni local references

Comment: post some of your application code

Answer (score 0):

To Delete the local reference, you need to add a line `env->DeleteLocalRef(jniRef)`, where `jniRef` is an object you are creating in JNI like `jstring` for example. The code in the link you shared will not cause a local reference table overflow. An overflow will only happen if you are doing a lot of object creation (usually in a loop). It has to happen in the context of a single function call, since all local references are automatically cleared when the function exits. Post some code for more help

Comment: I am using android phonegap app.When i continuously use the app,i am getting the above said error.In my app i am not using jni.I don't know how this error is occured.please guide me to avoid this error